# point document route of virtual host (crud-admin-generator)

Tags: php

I am working through the installation steps of [Crud Admin Generator](http://crud-admin-generator.com/) and trying to easily generate a backend application based on an existing database.

While working through the installation steps it says this:

> You need point the document root of your virtual host to
>   `/path_to/admingenerator/web`
>
> This is an example of VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /path_to/admingenerator/web
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   <Directory "/path_to/admingenerator/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride all
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
           php_admin_flag engine on
           php_admin_flag safe_mode off
           php_admin_value open_basedir none
        </ifModule>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Im not sure where to put this or how to finish the setup because Im stuck on this step.  Im using Mac OSx and MAMP server so all of my applications and such are stored in Applications/MAMP/htdocs

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

First, find the path to your `httpd.conf`. In my case, the path is as follows

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
```

Find and uncomment this line

```
# Virtual Hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

What I prefer to do is use `VirtualHosts` using `ServerName` directive to access your site by hitting `http://crud.com`. Open `/etc/hosts` and add the following line

```
127.0.0.1    crud.com
```

Then open the `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file and update it accordingly

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /path_to/admingenerator/web
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   ServerName crud.com
   ServerAlias www.crud.com 
   <Directory "/path_to/admingenerator/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride all
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
           php_admin_flag engine on
           php_admin_flag safe_mode off
           php_admin_value open_basedir none
        </ifModule>
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, restart the MAMP - your site should be running now under `http://crud.com`.